# AWS lambda@edge Invocation counts are not showing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

i am using lambda@edge when there is an event occured in Cloudfront

I can see the logs of lambda@edge in the nearest region from where the endpoint of cloudfront got hit.

I can't see the no of times my lambda got invoked (invocation counts), where do i see my lambda@edge invocation counts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug or incomplete feature in AWS Lambda console.